# Java method to get the Sub Directories in Azure Storage Blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

Here is the structure:

1. Root directory with more than one folder-> one of then "foo"
2. foo folder has child folder "foo1"
3. foo1 has various folders/contents

Now, I'd need to go to foo1. I was wondering if I should be reading foo and foo1 as a CloudBlobContainer or as a CloudBlob, if I read foo as Cloud Blob, it doesn't allow me to read foo1 as CloudBlob(couldn't find the method)

Comment: Is "foo" a container? Or is it a top-level folder inside a container?

Comment: can you remove the tag of "azure-java-sdk". You have asked about Dot Net SDK, and tag is misleading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one way to do this is to  get the `DirectoryReference` using the method.

```
CloudBlobContainer.getDirectoryReference({directoryname}}
```